# Is it possible to re-size a image in a uipasteboard xcode 7.2 Objective C?

Tags: xcode, uipasteboard

I’m currently using this code bellow in Xcode 7.2, which takes the image and pastes it in imessages etc. But it’s too large (in dimensions). Is it possible to make this image smaller?

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [pasteboard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not whilst it's in the pasteboard. BUT, if you're worried about it being the wrong size when you paste it somewhere, FEAR NOT, Apple have been kind to us and have built quite a lot of the presentation "resizing" into things for us.

What you need to do if you really HAVE to resize the image is:

1) Be lazy and use code which you can resume... i.e. I found this on here I believe:

```
- (NSImage *)imageResize:(NSImage*)anImage newSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    NSImage *sourceImage = anImage;
    [sourceImage setScalesWhenResized:YES];

    // Report an error if the source isn't a valid image
    if (![sourceImage isValid]){
        NSLog(@"Invalid Image");
    } else {
        NSImage *smallImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize];
        [smallImage lockFocus];
        [sourceImage setSize: newSize];
        [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
        [sourceImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [smallImage unlockFocus];
        return smallImage;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

then in the bit of code which you've given us:

```
    *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSImage *myShinyResizedImage = [self imageResize: oldImage newSize: CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0)];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myShinyResizedImage);
    [pasteboard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
```

And it's been resized before if goes off to get pasted elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, Adrian, It's not clear whether you are programming for iOS or OSX - you say "UIPastboard" which is on iOS, but your code shows "NSImage" which is an OS X class?

Comment: Apologies, but both apply :) UI and NS is 75% interchangeable. When it comes to CoreOS UIPasteboard and NSImage (NSPasteboard and UIImage) can be easily interchanged. In come cases, there might be API differences, but they're often minor.