# How to fix this error? Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode

Hi, I’m trying to resize a uipasteboard but I keep getting this error. Is there a way to fix this it?

This is the code I’m using:

```
- (NSImage *)imageResize:(NSImage*)anImage newSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    NSImage *sourceImage = anImage;
    [sourceImage setScalesWhenResized:YES];

    // Report an error if the source isn't a valid image
    if (![sourceImage isValid]){
        NSLog(@"Invalid Image");
    } else {
        NSImage *smallImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize];
        [smallImage lockFocus];
        [sourceImage setSize: newSize];
        [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
        [sourceImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [smallImage unlockFocus];
        return smallImage;

    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: please include your error

Comment: Expected Expression - (NSImage *)imageResize:(NSImage*)anImage newSize:(NSSize)newSize {

Comment: that is not an error, that is a function declaration.  not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: ah, ok, your last edit includes the error.  thanks.

Comment: I'm just a beginner, and it won't let me run my project, due to this error.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are programming for iOS or OSX - you say "UIPastboard" which is on iOS, but your code shows "NSImage" which is an OSX class

Comment: "resize a UIPasteboard"??????

Comment: Its IOS. here's the code that i was using:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762984/is-it-possible-to-re-size-a-image-in-a-uipasteboard-xcode-7-2-objective-c